# Trouble Parsing XML Data

Tags: android

I have an .xml file as follows:

```
<entry>
    <question>Which is larger? An elephant or a cat?</question>
    <answer>Elephant</answer>
</entry>
```

I am following a tutorial and am trying to parse the data from the .xml file into TextViews. However, in the following code, removing the else if block (located under the second while loop) will allow the app to run without fail, but leaving it in results in the application not responding. I've traced through the code, but I'm still having trouble with pinpointing the cause of the error.

```
    TextView tvQuestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvQuestion);
    TextView tvAnswer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvAnswer);

    XmlResourceParser parser = getResources().getXml(R.xml.qa);

    try
    {
        while(parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG)
        {
            if(parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG)
            {
                continue;
            }

            String name = parser.getName();

            if(name.equals("entry"))
            {
                String question = "";
                String answer = "";

                while(parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG)
                {
                    if(parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    name = parser.getName();

                    if(name.equals("question"))
                    {
                        question = readText(parser);
                        tvQuestion.setText(question);
                    }
                    else if(name.equals("answer"))
                    {
                        answer = readText(parser);
                        tvAnswer.setText(answer);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(XmlPullParserException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private String readText(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException
{
    String result = "";
    if(parser.next() == XmlPullParser.TEXT)
    {
        result = parser.getText();
        parser.nextTag();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: post error log as well.

Comment: Application Not Responding i.e. ANR is shown when the UI thread is blocked for 5 seconds or more. Likely your parser code has an infinite loop. Step the code in a debugger to learn why your parser loop is not terminating.

Comment: After stepping through the code, I found an infinite loop between the first while loop and the following if statement. To fix the issue, I added an extra conditional to the while statement: `while(parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG && parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this !

```
           DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder;
    try {
        dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes("utf-8"))));
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();


        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("entry");
        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

             Element element = (Element) nList.item(temp);

                 NodeList q= element.getElementsByTagName("question");
                 Element line = (Element) q.item(0);

                             String question = getCharacterDataFromElement(line);
                             tvQuestion.setText(question);

                 NodeList a = element.getElementsByTagName("answer");
                 line = (Element) a.item(0);

                             String answer = getCharacterDataFromElement(line);
                             tvAnswer.setText(answer);

        }
               } catch (Exception e) {

               }

public static String getCharacterDataFromElement(Element e) {
    Node child = e.getFirstChild();
    if (child instanceof CharacterData) {
      CharacterData cd = (CharacterData) child;
      return cd.getData();
    }
    return "";
}
```